# MS-SQL stored procedure binary to file

Tags: sql-server

Excuse me..
I will export file to D:\files\ from binary at table.
Col2 is the file name,col3 is the binary data.

How do I use stored procedure to do the work?

Comment: Welcome :)  Please make a complete question (and make it a little more clear too) See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for assistance.

Comment: Is the `D:\Files` folder on the database server?

Comment: I would recommend using SSIS or .Net rather than using a SP to access the file system.

Comment: D:\Files is not on the database server